# Trouble with Binding Item in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding

I developed a take-note app, used the ItemsNote to save the list of notes, and the ItemModifyNote to save the temporary item when modify.

```
public ObservableCollection<NoteViewModel> ItemsNote
{
    get
    {
        return _itemsNote;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemsNote = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemsNote");
    }
}        

public NoteViewModel ItemModifyNote { get; set; }
```

at Mainpage.xaml ( where I display the ItemsNote binding within a LongListSelector), I insert a "edit" button next to each note, so when I click it, I set the ItemModifyNote's data to selected item in ItemsNote, then navigate to the "modifyNotePage.xaml"

```
private void btEditNote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (sender as Button).DataContext as NoteViewModel;
    if (button != null)
    {
        int intIndex = App.ViewModel.ItemsNote.IndexOf(button);
        string modifyUri = "/Pages/NoteModifyPage.xaml?Id=" + intIndex.ToString();
        App.ViewModel.ItemModifyNote = App.ViewModel.ItemsNote.ElementAt(intIndex);                
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(modifyUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
```

at the ModifyNotePage.xaml, I modify the data of ItemModifyNote (which include a title and a content, both are string) by 2 textbox

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
    Text="{Binding ItemModifyNote.NoteTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="tbxModifyNoteTitle"
    FontFamily="Clear Sans Light" BorderThickness="0.0" 
    KeyDown="tbxModifyNoteTitle_KeyDown"/>
                    </Grid>

<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,20" 
    x:Name="tbxModifyNoteContent" Text="{Binding ItemModifyNote.NoteContent, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0.0" FontFamily="Clear Sans Light"
    GotFocus="tbxModifyNoteContent_GotFocus" LostFocus="tbxModifyNoteContent_LostFocus"/>
```

finally I use 2 buttons: Cancel and Save.
In Save button I set the data of item in ItemsNote by the data of ItemModifyNote

```
private void btCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.ItemsNote[key] = App.ViewModel.ItemModifyNote;                      
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

the problem is: even when I click the cancel button, the note still save the modify text ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `ItemModifyNote` references `NoteViewModel` instance from `ItemsNote`. Since both `TextBox` in edit page and `LongListSelector` in the main page operating on the same veiwmodel instance, when user modify `ItemModifyNote` property, `LongListSelector` will display updated value without any more code needed.

To avoid this behavior, in button edit click event handler method, try to create a new instance of `NoteViewModel` and copy it's properties value from the one in `ItemsNote`, instead of directly referencing the existing instance.

Comment: uhm, I've changed App.ViewModel.ItemModifyNote = App.ViewModel.ItemsNote.ElementAt(intIndex); with App.ViewModel.ItemModifyNote = new NoteViewModel(){NoteTitle = ..., NoteContent = ...}; , and this seem worked. Thanks ^^